# "Here is an image just for your eyes"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Here is an image just for your eyes

The context is that at the end of my writing, I would like to show a beautiful image that isn't related to the writing content. Does the above sentence correctly express that meaning?

Comment: It made me think the image was private, possibly because it was similar to the English idiom *for your eyes only*.

Comment: Why would you include an image that has nothing to do with your writing?  It's as if you are saying, "I realize that reading my writing was a chore, but here is something that will make up for it."  If it doesn't relate, don't show it.

Comment: @Jim, He don't want his readers to relate the image with his writing and so he wants it to be indicated to them. He wants it to be included along with the other content. Nothing wrong in it. I don't find any good reason which made you think like that.

Comment: @Jim, In my case, the writing content is pretty trivial. However, its “color” (meaning, what it stands for, ...) is bright, and so does the image I want to insert. I believe adding the image not only visually fills up all the blank spaces but also has a positive impact on readers’ feeling. Besides, the image is really beautiful ;)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence “Here is an image just for your eyes” does *not* suggest that you want to “show a beautiful image that isn't related to the writing content”.

The phrasing is slightly awkward and the sentence might be read as referring to eye-candy,  to personalization, or to secrecy.  That is, it may be interpreted as saying  “Here's some eye-candy for you to look at brainlessly”, or “This image is just for you”, or “This is an eyes-only image, not to be kept or copied”.

Rather than telling the reader what you expect the image to do for them, perhaps tell them what it meant to you, or how it made you feel.  For example:  “After I thought the dismal thoughts above, contemplating the picture below lifted my spirits.” 
[image]

Comment: O, Memtest86!  How you lift my spirits!